# Magento SOAP V2 API - Additional attributes sets empty

Tags: c#, api, magento, attributes

For a few hours now I've been trying to create a product via the SOAP V2 API with additional attributes. The product is being added whenever I call *catalogProductCreate* but the additional attributes I send with the request are set empty. Whenever I don't add the additional attributes both attributes are set on their default, so I've figured that the attributes are being send and received but not processed properly? I've tried everything, I've Googled but came up empty.

This is my code: (C#)

```
  catalogProductCreateEntity cpce = new catalogProductCreateEntity();
  associativeEntity[] attributes = new associativeEntity[2];
  attributes[0] = new associativeEntity();
  attributes[0].key = "product_state1";
  attributes[0].value = _stateofbox;

  attributes[1] = new associativeEntity();
  attributes[1].key = "product_state2";
  attributes[1].value = _stateofproduct;

  catalogProductAdditionalAttributesEntity additionalAttributes = new catalogProductAdditionalAttributesEntity();
  additionalAttributes.single_data = attributes;
  cpce.additional_attributes = additionalAttributes;
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it, I thought I had to set the plaintext/ID (0,1,2,3) of the pre-defined attributes inside the value of *associativeEntity*. Although, I found out that *catalogProductAttributeOptions* will tell you what ID your values have. Thus you have to call that method in order to find out what ID's you should use.

Comment: I'm having your same problem, could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: Instead of using the indices that the objects has because YOUR system has assigned them, you need to call  `catalogProductAttributeOptions` to retrieve the IDs that Magento uses to identify your objects.